# selecting parent() becomes different in what is supposed to be the same link <a>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So here is my problem:
I want to select the div with the class "read_more hidden".In the first link it selects it, but on the second one it doesn't.It says undefined..Could someone explain to me what's going on?

(I am trying to make "read more.." link  on a big text coming from the database)

**PHP**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $str==NULL;
    $offset==NULL;
    $max_length==NULL;
    $str=$row['subject'];
    $max_length = 3500;
    if (strlen($str) > $max_length)
    {
        $offset = ($max_length - 3) - strlen($str);
        $str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ' ', $offset)) . '<br></br><a class="clicky" href="">read more...</a>';
    }

    echo'<div class="GTextBorder" >
        <center>
        <h3>
        <em>';
        if ($row['title']==NULL)
        {
            echo 'No title';
        }
        else
        {
            echo ''.$row['title'].'';
        }

    echo '</em></h3></center><br></br>
            <div class="read_more hidden" >'.$row['subject'].'
                <a class="clickya" href=""><i>less...</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item" >'.$str.'</div>
        <br></br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br></br>';
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.clicky').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).parent().parent().prev().attr("class");
    window.alert(id);
});
```

*Some explanation:*
I first take the $row['subject'] which is the longtext and i check if it's more than 3500 chars.if it is then i put read more.. link so it can open.My first idea was to make two separate divs(one hidden) one normal so when read more.. is clicked the two divs would change.so read_more div would be shown and ".item" div would be hidden.But for some reason when the third long text is printed with read more.. link it just cant select the whole GTextBorder div. i don't know why.

Comment: The `read_more` DIV is `.parent().prev()`, not `.parent().parent().prev()`.

Comment: The database contains 3 text.first and 3rd are more than 3500 chars and when i press the first link the page it alerts "read_more hidden" and the second link alerts"undefined"

Comment: I don't see how it works at all. `this` is `a.clicky`, `.parent()` is `div.item`, and `parent().parent()` is `div.GTextBorder`. So how can `.prev()` get to `read_more` from there?

Comment: i dont have a clue...i am just saying what the results are...

Comment: Look in the DOM inspector, make sure all the nesting is the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: For some reason it creates a div.item inside the div.item on the third GTextBorder

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Are you sure you copied the code correctly? There's probably a missing `</div>` somewhere.